# PivotTable.ChangePivotCache is throwing Run-time error 5

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I'm struggling for days trying to fix this, so please help me.
I read everything I found about the topic and still can not find a solution.

**What I have:**

- Manually created Pivot table in **shReport**
- Range data in **Sheet1** (dynamically changing by rows)
- 4 slicers of the Pivot table
- Office 365 running at Win10

**What I need to do:**

- Changing data source range of the Pivot table (via VBA)

**What I tried:**

- xlPivotTableVersion14, xlPivotTableVersion12, PvtTbl.Version, not specifying version at all
- DataArea as String & as Range (this is the new/expanded source range)
- Create cache inside/after the .ChangePivotCache method and in a separate variable of type PivotCache

**What's the problem:**
Run-time error '5' (Invalid procedure call or argument) at line **PvtTbl.ChangePivotCache pc**

**Notes:**

- ?shReport.PivotTables.Count  - 1
- ?DataArea.Address  - $A$1:$J$20
- ?ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Count returns 1 before and after **pc** is set

  ```
  Sub ChangePivotTableCache(sh As Worksheet, ptName As String)

      Dim PvtTbl  As PivotTable
      Dim DataArea As Range
      Dim pc As PivotCache

      With Sheet1
          Set DataArea = .Range("A1:J" & .Range("A100000").End(xlUp).Row)
      End With

      On Error Resume Next
      Set PvtTbl = sh.PivotTables(ptName)
      On Error GoTo 0

      If Not PvtTbl Is Nothing Then
          Set pc = ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=DataArea, Version:=PvtTbl.Version)
          PvtTbl.ChangePivotCache pc
      Else
          MsgBox "Pivot Table doesn't exist in this worksheet!"
      End If

  End Sub
  ```

Any ideas guys?

Comment: What is the existing data source for the pivot table?

Comment: The existing data source is the same range -  Sheet1 -A1:J18